# How to manage a systemd service which needs multiple processes?

Tags: linux, crash, process, systemd

I have a website which requires several processes to be running (python, node, etc). I currently have a systemd service created so I can easily start and stop those processes. I created a start script which launches all of the processes I need as background processes (appending `&` to the end of the command).

This prevents me from being able to make use of systemd's auto restart feature when something crashes since all of the processes are starting under a single script.

One potential solution I can think of would be to create a service for each process, and then link them all together by creating a master service which `Requires` them. I'm not a fan of this because it means I need to create 4-5 services for every environment of this website I want to run.

Is there a way I can easily define a service that starts multiple processes and monitors each of them individually?

Comment: Your potential solution is the correct one. Otherwise you are trying to re-implement what systemd is already doing for you: starting/stopping services taking into account their dependencies.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create several *template* services, which are named with an `@` like this:

- `website@.service`
- `pythonthingy@.service`
- `nodethingy@.service`

Using templates, you can start a named instance for each website:

```
systemctl start pythonthingy@clientone.service nodethingy@clientone.service
systemctl start pythonthingy@clienttwo.service nodethingy@clienttwo.service
```

Within such template units, you can use `%i` to reference the instance name ("clientone" in this example). So the "main" unit (service or target) could have:

```
[Unit]
Requires=pythonthingy@%i.service
...
[Service]
Environment="DOCROOT=/var/www/%i"
```

If each site needs multiple parameters, you can load them from a file:

```
[Service]
EnvironmentFile=/etc/someconfigdir/%i.conf
```

If some sites need nonstandard unit settings compared to the rest, use drop-ins:

- `pythonthingy@.service` – the common template
- `pythonthingy@clientone.service.d/overrides.conf` – extra parameters just for client 1

Templates, drop-ins, and expansions like %i are explained in [systemd.unit(5)](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.unit.html).